# How to optimize cypher query by PROFILE result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a database with about 10,000 nodes.  I ran the following query through the profiler and received an unexpected number of db hits.  This query is supposed find all employees from a given user uid.  On a real dataset, I get back 9 rows.

```
PROFILE MATCH (:User {uid:{0}})<-[:manages]-(employee)
RETURN employee
```

I receive the following output from the profiler.  Why am I getting such a high number of db hits here?  What can change?

```
Projection
  |
  +Expand(All)
    |
    +Filter
      |
      +NodeByLabelScan

+-----------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|        Operator | EstimatedRows | Rows | DbHits |                    Identifiers |                           Other |
+-----------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|      Projection |            38 |    9 |      0 | anon[64], anon[7], employee    |                     employee    |
|     Expand(All) |            38 |    9 |     10 | anon[64], anon[7], employee    | ()<-[:manages]-(employee)       |
|          Filter |            34 |    1 |    342 |                        anon[7] |  anon[7].uid == {  AUTOSTRING0} |
| NodeByLabelScan |           342 |  342 |    343 |                        anon[7] |                      :User      |
+-----------------+---------------+------+--------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 695
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an index on `User(uid)`:

`CREATE INDEX ON :User(uid)`

Or create a uniqueness constraint (which will also create an index):

`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.uid IS UNIQUE`

Creating an index will enable a lookup by index operation instead of `NodeByLabelScan` which will be much more efficient.

Comment: Wow, it went down to 11 db hits!